# add_polygon in mapdeck zooms out the map

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

When I add a simple map to my shiny application, without adding polygons, the zoom argument works correctly, and the map initializes as it should.

On the other hand, when I add polygons with add_polygon(), the map is initialized more zoomed out than it should.

Why is this happening?

This is my code:

```
library(mapdeck)
library(sf)

sf = st_as_sf(my_LargeSpatialPolygonDataframe)

output$my_map = renderMapdeck({

    mapdeck(token = mytoken, location = c(a, b), zoom = 12,
            bearing = -45.00, pitch = 0, style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9') %>%

    add_polygon(data = sf,
                stroke_colour = "#000000",
                stroke_width = 20,
                stroke_opacity = 200,
                fill_opacity = 0,
                layer = "init_polygons")
})
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and the packages you're using (`sf`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a layer through one of the `add_` functions, the layer will calculate the zoom level required to fit the whole of the data in the frame of the window. You can stop this behaviour using `update_view = FALSE`

Here's a reproducible example

#### setting location in mapdeck()

Here the `add_polygon()` layer will re-zoom the map to show all the data in the layer. This is the behaviour you're seeing.

```
library(mapdeck)

set_token("MAPBOX_TOKEN")

mapdeck(
  location = c(144.9, -37.8)
  , zoom = 11
  , bearing = -45.00
  , pitch = 0
  , style = mapdeck_style("light")
  ) %>%
  add_polygon(
    data = spatialwidget::widget_melbourne
    , stroke_colour = "#000000"
    , stroke_width = 20
    , stroke_opacity = 200
    , fill_opacity = 0
    , layer_id = "init_polygons"
    )
```

[image]

#### using update_view = FALSE

This tells the layer to not update the view, so your original `location()` values will be used.

```
mapdeck(
  location = c(144.9, -37.8)
  , zoom = 11
  , bearing = -45.00
  , pitch = 0
  , style = mapdeck_style("light")
  ) %>%
  add_polygon(
    data = spatialwidget::widget_melbourne
    , stroke_colour = "#000000"
    , stroke_width = 20
    , stroke_opacity = 200
    , fill_opacity = 0
    , layer_id = "init_polygons"
    , update_view = F
    )
```

[image]